# join diffrent field type in linq

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

join diffrent field type in linq

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string CategoryID
    {
        get { return Myclass.increse(CategoryID); }
        set { CategoryID = value; }
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

public partial class ProductCategory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
var query = (from c in dContext.ProductCategories
                    join p in dContext.Products
                     on Myclass.EncodeMD5(c.ID.ToString()) equals p.CategoryID
                    select new { id = p.ID, cat = p.CategoryID, name = p.Name, cat1 = c.Name }
                  ).ToList();
```

The field should be converted to string
  Then function runs EncodeMD5

error:

> *LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   EncodeMD5(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.*

Comment: Now what is the question....?

Comment: are you sure that example fits that error message? in that example, LINQ can see the `EncodeMD5` method and the `CategoryID` property (both of which I would expect it to complain about), but you aren't showing it `increse`

Comment: Was corrected LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String EncodeMD5(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call arbitrary .NET methods in LINQ-to-(some database backend) - the entire point of EF (etc) is that it wants to create SQL from your expression - something involving a `where` clause. It can work with simple properties and operators, and a few methods it knows about and can map into SQL, but it can't perform something it has never heard of (`increse`, `EncodeMD5`, etc) how would it know what SQL to write?

With something like MD5, your best bet would be to store the MD5 hash in the underlying table ***along with*** the ID.  Likewise with the `CategoryID`'s "increse" (whatever that is). So your query would end up working off these pre-calculated values:

```
on c.IDHash equals p.CategoryIDHash
```